# WC_Product_Query not working with have_posts()

Tags: wordpress, loops, woocommerce, product

I am trying to loop through my WooCommerce products like you would with Custom Post Types. But for some reason this method isn't working. I am getting an error which is to do with me using `have_posts()`. What am I doing wrong?

**Error**

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on array

**My code**

```
<?php
 $query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
     'limit' => 10,
     'orderby' => 'date',
     'order' => 'DESC'
 ) );

 $products = $query->get_products();

 if( $products->have_posts() ) {
    while( $products->have_posts() ) {
      $products->the_post();
      echo the_permalink();
    }
} ?>
```

**Update**

I have found that using a foreach loop does work like the following;

```
<?php
foreach( $products as $product ) {
    echo $product->get_title();
} ?>
```

But I'd still like to understand why this method doesn't work with `have_posts()`

Comment: Use simple `WP_Query` if you want to use `have_post` with simple parameters return by the query and not use of product object there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$query = new WC_Product_Query(array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
        ));

$products = $query->get_products();

if (!empty($products)) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {

        echo get_permalink($product->get_id());
    }
}
```

function `have_post()` is member function of WordPress `WP_Query` class - and WooCommerce `WC_Product_Query` class is extending `WC_Object_Query` class, not the `WP_Query` - So this function cannot be called

Answer (score 1):

Because $products is array, so you can't call a method in it, just at some item. If you did $products[0]->have_posts() it would work.